# on click of button i want the selected field id to be passed to the given path

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

i have a loop in which i have select options with dynamic id's, what i want is that on selection of option of specific id select menu option that id of that option should pass through button to controller.

This is What I've done:

```
    .container_fluid2
  %table#myTable.table.table-striped.my-4.w-50.table_prop
    %thead
      %tr.style_bg
        %th{:onclick => "sortTable(0)","data-priority" => "0"} Requested User
        %th{:onclick => "sortTable(0)","data-priority" => "0"} Institution
        %th{:onclick => "sortTable(0)","data-priority" => "0"} Role Selection
        %th{:onclick => "sortTable(0)","data-priority" => "0"} Actions
    %tbody
      - @InstitutionUserRole.each do |q|
        %tr{id: "InstitutionUserRole_#{q.id}"}
          %td.color_tr
            = q.user.email
          %td.color_tr
            = q.institution.name
          %td.color_tr
            %select.select2.role_select{:id => "my-dropdown_#{q.user.id}"}
              %option{:value => "1"} Curbside Admin
              %option{:value => "2"} Institution Authorized Member
              %option{:value => "3"} Institution Editorial Manager
              %option{:value => "4"} Institution Administration Manager
              %option{:value => "4"} Institution Operations Manager
              %option{:value => "5"} Institution Editorial & Operations Manager
              %option{:value => "6"} Institution Administration & Operations Manager
              %option{:value => "7"} Institution Workgroup Member
              %option{:value => "8"} Institution Workgroup Admin
              %option{:value => "10"} Institution Content Authorized Member
              %option{:value => "11"} External Contributor
              %option{:value => "12"} External Reviewer
              %option{:value => "13"} Curbside Content Manager
          %td.color_tr
            %button.w3-btn.w3-white.w3-border.w3-round-large{:id => "go-btn_#{q.user.id}",:onclick => "location.href='#{admin_role_selection_path(id: q.user.id,)}';", :type => "button"} Approve
```

[That's my View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGwQy.png)

Comment: Can anybody Help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Help on SO can take a while. The members are all over the world and they don't continuously monitor various interests so it can take a week. Remember, we don't get paid so you're relying on us to help in our spare time. While you're waiting please fix the grammar in your question as it is important on SO; It's not a message board, it's more like an online encyclopedia so capitalization and punctuation matter. "i" -> "I", "id's, what" -> "id's. What", "That's my View" -> "This is my view" etc. While it might seem fussy or silly it affects people's willingness to help.